# How can I access hard drive in my laptop using live tails OS?

Tags: tails

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.I am also using live tails OS using USB pendrive.But when I use live OS I cann't access my hard drive's file which is saved in my laptop using primary OS(Ubuntu 14.04).It requires administrator password.I used my login password but not worked.What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to more options on the Tails Greeter menu and set an Administration Password, this password can then be used to mount and access internal disks.

Follow the guide in the [Tails documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/encryption_and_privacy/your_data_wont_be_saved_unless_explicitly_asked/index.en.html#access_hdd).